# Access to active page html code from chrome extension background.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I can't get access to html code of active tab (page) from background.js script of my extension

manifest.json

```
"background": {
  "scripts": ["jquery.js","background.js"]
},
```

background.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(info) {
    return {redirectUrl: "http://www.mysite.com/script.php?" +
                        "data=" + encodeURIComponent($('#J_Data').text())};
  },
  {
  urls: [
    "http://www.othersite.com/addItems.do*"
  ],
  types: ["script"]
},
["blocking"]);
```

But background.js have no access to active page html code and "$('#J_Data').text()" undefined!
How I can get access to active page with background.js and jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing jQuery in the context of the background script and it does not have access to the page itself. You will want to look into using [chrome.tabs.executeScript](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi) or [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) to inject code into the tabs you are interested in. What you will probably have to do is inject a script into tabs, if there are links you are interested in, [pass them to the background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html) and store in a temporary index of tabIds/urls with the data to include and query that index within the onBeforeRequest listener.

Comment: I tried chrome.tabs.executeScript but redirectUrl return url before executeScript will finished. If I put redirectUrl to chrome.tabs.executeScript callback function, chrome doesn't use redirectUrl. Now I use content script and get data before using redirectUrl. Thanks. @abraham